# Screen freezes while shutting down

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

When i try to shutdown my pc the screen often freezes when the ubuntu logo appears forcing me to hard shutdown the pc(pressing the power button)... I face this problem after every 4/10 times i shutdown my pc